# ng-click inside ng-repeat while assiging a variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i am trying to assign a variable on an ng-click inside an ng-repeat like so:

```
<ul ng-repeat="stocksInPortfolio in ctrl.myPortfolio.stocksInPortfolio">
  <li><a href ng-click="collapse = {{stocksInPortfolio.stock._id}}">{{stocksInPortfolio.stock.name | limitTo:10}}...</a></li>
  <li>{{stocksInPortfolio.stock._id}}</li>
  <h1>this collapse is {{collapse}}</h1>
</ul>
```

but it is not working, and I am not sure what I should be doing to assign this variable to make the variable assignment dynamic.

Comment: ng-click doesn't need interpolation, try `ng-click="collapse = stocksInPortfolio.stock._id"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the brackets `{{ }}` in ng-click!

```
<ul ng-repeat="stocksInPortfolio in ctrl.myPortfolio.stocksInPortfolio">
  <li><a href ng-click="collapse = stocksInPortfolio.stock._id">{{stocksInPortfolio.stock.name | limitTo:10}}...</a></li>
  <li>{{stocksInPortfolio.stock._id}}</li>
  <h1>this collapse is {{collapse}}</h1>
</ul>
```